# Slow Rendering During VisionOS Image Tracking

Tags: image, tracking, realitykit, visionos

I am following this documentation on tracking images in 3D space on Vision Pro. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionos/tracking-images-in-3d-space

The expected result is that a 3D sphere will smoothly track a moving reference image. However, when I run the app, the 3D sphere will only update positions about twice a second or so. There's not a lot of documentation for troubleshooting. Is there some sort of render function I should be calling to have the RealityView render more quickly?

```
import SwiftUI
import ARKit
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent

struct ImmersiveView: View {
    var arkitSession = ARKitSession()

    @State var entityMap : [UUID: ModelEntity] = [:]
    let imageInfo = ImageTrackingProvider(
        referenceImages: ReferenceImage.loadReferenceImages(inGroupNamed: "ref")
    )
    var material = SimpleMaterial()

    var rootEntity = Entity()

    func updateImage(_ anchor: ImageAnchor) {
        if entityMap[anchor.id] == nil {
            // Add a new entity to represent this image.
            let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.05))
            entityMap[anchor.id] = entity
            rootEntity.addChild(entity)
        }

        if anchor.isTracked {
            entityMap[anchor.id]?.transform = Transform(matrix: anchor.originFromAnchorTransform)
        }

    }

    var body: some View {

        RealityView { content in
            // Add the initial RealityKit content
            content.add(rootEntity)

            Task {
                try await arkitSession.run([imageInfo]);
                for await update in imageInfo.anchorUpdates {
                    updateImage(update.anchor)
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: A good start would be to remove `var arkitSession = ARKitSession()` from the `View`. SwiftUI can recreate views whenever it wants and that property is not safe from being recreated. Also, that floating `Task` is unnecessary `make` is compatible with `async/await` and you can put the updates under `.task`

Comment: Thank you for the tip, lorem ipsum. I moved the ARKitSession() line outside the view and moved Task's contents to .task. Still unsure why it won't render more frequently.

Comment: Do you have any updates? I do have the same problem here. It does not make a difference if i use a AnchorEntity with Imagedetection or the running ARKitSession. Both are very slow on updates.

Comment: See here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/747118. It seems to be working as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the Apple Developer Forums, ImageTrackingProvider on VisionOS currently seems to fire anchorUpdates quite slowly, leading to inability to smoothly track moving images. I filed an enhancement request via the Feedback Assistant and encourage others to do the same.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/747118

Answer (score 0):

I worked with Unity on the Vision Pro and I also saw this behaviour. I could not find any official documentation from Apple about this issue, but it seems like updating the position of a tracking image on visionOS is not very smooth at the moment.

Source: I asked a Unity dev if this was a problem with Unity or VisionOS. It seem to be the latter. Hopefully they will improve this in the future.

[Unity Forum Post](https://discussions.unity.com/t/official-support-for-visionos-release-notes-1-1-4/340680/21)

Comment: It definitely seems to do with position updates being provided asynchronously, so the main thread is not receiving the state changes. The position updates are being provided smoothly, but the main thread does not re-render the scene in response to state changes at the same rate. I am still working to see if there's a solution :)

Comment: Ah? So just to be sure, you get __different__ positions for the image tracker at a high framerate?